# Filter SubForm based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Form with a SubForm, i'm trying to filter based on a range of two dates and an Username (i take the criteria from 3 textboxes), the part of the dates works fine but when i press the button to start the filter, a pop-up shows saying "Enter parameter value" (even if i type the username in the textbox), i enter an username and filters correctly, but the parameter its kept and the filter won't work anymore, until i close the Form and open again, any ideas?

I don't know why ask me to enter a parameter if i have already the username in the textbox.

Here my code:

```
Private Sub Filter_Click()

    Dim QIL As Form
    Set QIL = Forms("QIL")

If IsNull(Me.username_textbox) Or IsNull(Me.date_from_textbox) Or IsNull(Me.date_to_textbox) Then
    MsgBox "Insert date or username"
Else
    With Me.Superlinks_subform.Form
        .Filter = "[Date] = #" & Format(Me.date_from_textbox, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & _
     "# AND #" & Format(Me.date_to_textbox, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# AND [User] = " & Me.username_textbox.Value & ""
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
  End If

End Sub
```

Regards

Diego.

Comment: Have you tried a format string like `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `mm\/dd\/yyyy`? Also, assuming `Username` is a `String` - include single quotes like this: `[User] = '" & Me.username_textbox.Value & "'"` - Also, it is a bad idea to use a field name like `Date` since it is also a reserved word. (but it will work)

Comment: Hi braX, thanks a lot for your answer, indeed, the single quotes were missing, have a great day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the field [User] is a String - include single quotes like this:

```
[User] = '" & Me.username_textbox.Value & "'"
```